# Netbeans: can I configure to flag calls to non-exist functions and invalid signatures? (PHP)

Tags: php, netbeans, configuration, signature

*Class A*

```
class A {
    public foo( Apple $apple )
    {
      //whatever
    }
}
```

*YetAnotherFile.php* (in the same project)

```
$a = new A;

$a->foo( 42 );  // I really would like a little warning flag here
$a->foo( new Apple(), 'howdy' );  // I really would like...
$a->bar();  // I really would like...
```

I hope I got my own example right, anyway I hope you get my point.

Thank you...

Comment: PHP isn't JAVA and thus there mostly isn't any type checking within any IDE (at least not in Netbeans, Eclipse or Aptana).

Comment: Ever since `type hinting` http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) there is, at least in some IDEs ...